# Fix Size of Login Box in Drupal Theme

Tags: php, css, drupal, safari, themes

I've asked this question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733251/change-size-of-user-password-login-box), and thought it was fixed, however, it is only fixed in firefox.  In Safari the login box is now very wide, jutting out over the page contents. [Here is what it looks like in Safari](http://jonrwilson.com/safari_login.png), and [here is what it looks like in Firefox](http://jonrwilson.com/firefox_login.png).

I originally went about fixing it by creating a drupal module which changed the input "size" from 15 or to 43. I put my widerlogin.module [code up on paste bin here](http://drupal.pastebin.com/m5759d96d), where a kind person helped me to where I am now. 43 was chosen by adjusting the number with firebug until it looked good, however, in safari there is no firebug, so I don't know what's going on to make it so wide.  (it's also messed up on the iphone, presumably because it is safari)

Thanks in advance for your help!
Oh, and the site that all this is happening on is innovatefortomorrow.org if you want to look at it for some reason.

Comment: For me, the input fields are overflowing in FF3.0.15, IE7 and Safari

Comment: It could have been that I'm using FF 3.5.5, so I wasn't getting the long box in FF, but was in Safari.  Maybe FF 3.5.5 has an error, and the others were correct, which would make some kind of sense with a "size" number like 43, after starting with 15.  Obviously I have no idea though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few CSS rules can fix the problem:

```
/*
 Make the login boxes stretch to the full container
*/
#edit-name {
 width: 100%;
}
#edit-pass {
 width: 100%;
}

/* 
 Add a little padding so the boxes don't stretch too far.
*/
#block-user-0 {
 padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! it worked! Makes me sad that I bothered making a module and all that other junk, when a little css is all I needed.  It also makes me wonder what I tried initially that didn't work, since #edit-name makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot, I think I'll go ahead and delete the module I made earlier since this works in safari as well! the padding would work, but doesn't because of how I had already themed the box.  I ended up using "#edit-name, #edit-pass { width: 165px;}" which works perfectly in both safari and firefox. Thanks!